# Вывод символов с нижним регистром и верхним регистром

Tags: c++

Стоит задача, водится строка, при выводе должно быть две строки, одна выводит символы только верхнего регистра, вторая только нижнего.
Начал писать, цикл для определения нижнего регистра, выводит все, но останавливается если на его пути встречается символ с верхним регистром. Как правильно исправить код?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int str0=0;
    char str[100],str1, str2;

    cout << "Строка: ";
    cin >> str;
    while (str[str0])
    {

        str1 = str[str0];
        if (islower(str1)) {
            cout << str1;
            str0++;
        }

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваша программа должна работать только для английского? Или только для английского и русского?

Comment: @Unick на этот счет не было указаний, поэтому пока делаю только для английского

Comment: Ну, вам уже ответили, я же проедусь по вашей манере именовать переменные - не стоит так делать, что `str` - массив, `str0` - целочисленный индекс, а `str1` - вообще символ. Сами же запутаетесь, не говоря уж о других. Вы же не партизан, пишущий программы для гестапо? И еще - ну и какой вообще смысл в переменной `str1`?

Comment: @Harry создавая их я рассчитывал что, переменная str1 будет отвечать за вывод только нижнего регистра, а str2, соответственно для вывода верхнего регистра, ну на этом я застрял, не догоняю как дальше дописать цикл для верхнего регистра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str0++; надо вынести из if.

Вот так:

```
while (str[str0])
{
    str1 = str[str0];
    if(islower(str1)) 
    {
        cout << str1;
    }
    str0++;
}
```

А иначе при встрече символа в верхнем регистре у вас инкремент индекса прекращается, и вы зацикливаетесь на этом символе навсегда.